# IBrowserFile validation, whenever a IBrowserFile changes

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have recently started to fiddle Blazor so I have found when I have changed the IBrowserFile in my model(as an instance) the custom validation attribute doesn't seem to work,
how it is set in my page

```
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
   <div div="form-control row">
                <label for="@RegisterModel.File" class="col-form-label">File:</label>
                <InputFile @bind-Value="@RegisterEmployeeModel.File" OnChange="@LoadFiles" class="form-control-file"></InputFile>
                <ValidationMessage For="(()=>RegisterModel.File)"/>
</div>
```

the property field in the model

```
   [FileTypeValidation]
   public IBrowserFile File { get; set; } = null;
```

now I Wonder why the Validation doesnt happen whenever the file changes/is selected?
  shouldn't trigger the validation with the custom ValidationAttribute attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the validation happens when the form submits and not when the file changes